# How to call the same function on multiple classes?

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I have an UIViewController with 4 UIButtons. A user can tap any of those UIButtons and an UIView pops up. I want to add an `didAppear()` and `didDisappear()` function on the classes which are holding the UIViews depending on the users action. How can I call `didDisappear()` without the use of an enum, for example:

```
func didDisappear(view: EnumViews){
    switch view{
        case view0: myClassWithView0.didDisappear()
        case view1: myClassWithView1.didDisappear()
        case view2: myClassWithView2.didDisappear()
        case view3: myClassWithView3.didDisappear()
    }
}
```

Now I get 4 times duplicate data. I know that function exists for my class with a UIView, but how to call it? I made a protocol:

```
protocol ViewProtocol{
    func didAppear()
    func didDisappear()
}
```

I made the classes which are holding the UIView's conform to that protocol. However I do not know how to use it, when I create the class I get the error:

> 'myClassWithUIView' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible
>   initializers

The classes are all in an array and I can identify which UIView needs to pop up from the sender.tag. Ideally, I want to have something like this:

```
@IBAction func bringNewUIView(_ sender: UIButton) {
let newView = myArrayOfClassesWithUIView[sender.tag]
newView.didAppear()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got many things going on here.  I'll start with the easy one.

> 'myClassWithUIView' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers

This just means you don't have an initializer for your class.  So inside your `myClassWithUIView` implementation you need to have `init`.  I can't really help you with building the `init` because I don't know how that class is structured, but I will assume this is something you know how to do anyway.

Your `@IBAction` seems fine.  Once you have an array of your classes that seems like it should work.  Edit your post if that is not the case.

Finally, for your `didDisappear` question, you can do something like this:

```
func didDisappear(view: EnumViews) {
  //Check to see if this view conforms to your ViewProtocol (that's not a good name, btw)
  if let myClass = view as? ViewProtocol {
    //Since it does conform to ViewProtocol you can call didDisappear on it
    myClass.didDisappear()
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you already know that the `didDisappear` function is always passing in a view that conforms to `ViewProtocol` why not just change the argument and make that easier?

```
func didDisappear(view: ViewProtocol) {
  view.didDisappear()
}
```

Comment: Yea I know I used some easy words to let the people see what I mean :)